Spring integration - custom ISOEntities inject
I'm using spring integration for execute xml element extraction:
<bean id="myDmTypeXPathExpression" class="org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactoryBean">
    <property name="expression" value="/root/level0/*[last()]/local-name()"/>
</bean>
    
<int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>
    <int-xml:header name="dmType" xpath-expression-ref="myDmTypeXPathExpression" overwrite="true"/>
</int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>

In the input I have xml files with ISOEntities into DOCTYPE:
<!DOCTYPE mydocument [
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "ent/ISOEntities">
%ISOEntities;
]>

all ISOEntities are on my local catalog.
For validate my catalog I have an unitary test like this:
@Test
void check_document_parse() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    Resource xmlResource = loadMyXmlWithISOEntities();

    // WHEN
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(loadMyCatalogResolver());
    
    // THEN
    documentBuilder.parse(xmlResource.getFile());
}

My spring integration process throw exception:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: path/to/my/app/ent/ISOEntities at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1910) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:646) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1301) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1237) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.startPE(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:739) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.skipSeparator(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:2108) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:2071) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDInternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:363) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1128)
Is it possible to set entity resolver?

Please, share more stack trace about that error, so we would know the place of failure. Also you just don't share what exactly transformer you are talking about.

Hi Artem, I edited my question.

Still not clear what exactly is your configuration which throws that exception.
